# $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n$ is irreducible iff $a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n$ is irreducible

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I want to prove that $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n$ is irreducible in $K[x]$ (where $K$ is a field) if and only if $a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n$ is irreducible, knowing that $a_0\cdot a_n \neq 0$. How can I do this?

Comment: It suffices to note that the map $(a_0 + \cdots + a_nx^n) \mapsto a_0 x^n + \cdots + a_n$ is a homomorphism

Comment: the last polynomial is  $x^{n}p(1/x)$

Comment: Note that in English $K$ is a _field_, not a "body".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A transformation of F\[x\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270991/a-transformation-of-fx). See also [Irreducibility of the polynomial $a_{n}+a_{n-1}x+\cdots+a_{0}x^{n}$ when irreducibility of $a_{0}+a_{1}x+\cdots+a_{n}x^{n}$ is given](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412440) and [Prove that the polynomial $x^nf(1/x)$ with reverted coefficients is also irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963477),

Comment: [Irreducibility of reciprocal polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089464), [Prove that $f(x)$ is irreducible iff its reciprocal polynomial $f^*(x)$ is irreducible.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758745)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \dots + a_n x^n\in \Bbb{K}[x]$ is **not** irreducible, i.e., there is $q, r\in \Bbb{K}[x]$ such that $\deg(q), \deg(r) > 0$ and $p = qr$.

We know that $\deg(p) = \deg(q) + \deg(r)$, so we may assume WLG that

1. $q(x) = b_0 + b_1 x + \dots +b_m x^m$
2. $r(x) = c_0 + c_1 x + \dots + c_{n-m} x^{n-m}$

Then

$\begin{aligned}
a_0 x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} + \dots + a_n &=\\
x^n p\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) &=\\
x^n q\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)r\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) &=\\
x^m q\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) x^{n-m} r\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) &=\\
(b_0 x^m + b_1 x^{m-1} + \dots + b_m)(c_0 x^{n-m} + c_1 x^{n-m-1} + \dots + c_{n-m})
\end{aligned}$

Therefore $a_0 x^n + a_1 x^{n-1} + \dots + a_n$ is **not** irreducible.

The implication in the opposite direction is analogous.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x\to \frac{1}{z}$. We get

$$a_0+a_1\frac{1}{z}+\ldots+a_n\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^n=\frac{1}{z^n}\left(a_0z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n\right)=\frac{1}{z^n}q(z)$$
$p(z)$ is irreducible iff $q(z)$ is irreducible.

Comment: I don't think your first statement if true. $p(x)=(x^2+1)\cdot(x^2+2)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ and it doesn't have any roots in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @fdez Right! It is not necessary, anyway